# VSCode workspace slow for snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have this snippet when I type `c + tab` it auto-write `console.log($1)`

On all my workspaces it's going fast as lightning, but on one workspace it takes 5 to 6 seconds.

I can't find why, and find what sort of cache-to-purge specific to a worskpace needs to be clear.

Any idea ?

Comment: could you add a pic of the size of workspace you are working on?

Comment: @Ruthvik what do you mean ?

Comment: I'm asking how many files are present in the directory you are working on?